# Displaying results of query to Oracle database in dataGrid

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, winforms

I am struggling to make my dataGrid viev results of query. Connection with database is fine. Here is sample of my code:

```
            using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection())
            {
            conn.ConnectionString = "properConnectionString"
            conn.Open();

                OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                cmd.CommandText = "select * FROM WORKERS";
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

                OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            using (OracleDataAdapter orclDataAdapter = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd))
            {
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                orclDataAdapter.Fill(dt);


                dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
            }
        }
```

Comment: What is the problem? Datagrid is empty? Did you confirm that you are getting some data back?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your call to the Oracle database is actually returning data, you're missing the databind statement on the gridview.  Add this:

```
dataGridView1.DataBind();
```

place it right after the `dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;` line of code.

Comment: @NoSaidTheCompiler

I think i have problems with getting some data back with my call. Do you know possible reasons?
Here is screenshot:
http://imgur.com/a/pfem2

Comment: One way to see if your query returns data is to place a break at `dataGridView1.DataSource = dt`, run the program and when it breaks at the line of code, at the command windows type: `? dt.rows.count`  If the result is greater than zero, you have data.  But you are never going to see the data without the `databind` statement.